# Why this code is doing wrong calculations?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, substring

When debugging this code I noticed that the value of sum as mentioned in code tend to give wrong results. I cant understand why this is happening.

My program takes a string calculate its substrings and count the number of vowels present in all the substrings, the last sum value is the sum of all the vowel counts simultaneously

I've already tried debugging through the code and can't understand what's wrong with the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long int t,j,n,l,count=0,sum=0;
cin>>t;
string s;
//char i;
while(t>0)
{
    l=0;
    sum=0;
   count=0;
    cin  >>  s;
    n= s.length();
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(s[j]=='a' || s[j]=='e' || s[j]=='i' || s[j]=='o' || s[j]=='u' || s[j]=='A'|| s[j]=='E' || s[j]=='I' ||s[j]=='O' || s[j]=='U')
        {
              count++;
             l=j;

             cout<<"l="<<j<<endl;
             cout<<"j="<<j<<endl;
             cout<<"n="<<n<<endl;
             cout<<"n-1="<<n-1<<endl;
             cout<<"j+1="<<j+1<<endl;

            sum=sum+((n-l)*(j+1));

            cout<<"SUM is="<<sum << endl;
        }
    }
     if(l==0)
        {
            sum=0;
        }
        cout<<"Second part Sum="<<endl;
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    t--;
}

}
```

Program compiles and runs with no error messages.  However, there are logical errors because the calculations of sum are incorrect...[image]

Why is that sum = 20 ?, It should be 25 or 35...

For clarification, this is the problem statement for this solution:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/complexity-analysis/time-and-space-complexity/practice-problems/algorithm/vowel-game-f1a1047c/

Comment: Screen shot :https://gofile.io/?c=SgS3lw

Comment: What exactly is your program supposed to do?

Comment: @ManLaw My program takes a string,calculate its substrings and count the number of vowels present in all the substrings, the last sum value is the sum of all the vowel counts simultaneously, Its working correctly but I have some doubts about the calculation of sum value , it should be 25 or 35 not 20

Comment: Please [edit] to explain that inside your question.

Comment: Could it be because you are setting sum to 0 jndide your loop `while (t > 0)`? Or the `if (l == 0)` bit?  More generally if you put more effort jnto your varuable names (i.e. more letters e.g. inStr instead of s, i have no idea what t or l are meant to be) and indented properly, it might be easier to follow.

Comment: @GMc "t" is the no of test cases

Comment: @Yunnosch I've already edited the question

Comment: @GMc I thought of that but I'm not reaching to any conclusion there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output given by your program is correct. why you think it should be 25/30?

You wrote

```
sum=sum+((n-l)*(j+1));
```

when j = 1 then l=j=1
So (n-l)*(j+1)=(6-1)*(1+1)=5*2=10

So sum = sum+(n-l)*(j+1)=0+10=10

when j=4 then l=j=4

So (n-l)*(j+1)=(6-4)*(4+1)=2*5=10

So sum = sum+(n-l)*(j+1)=10+10=20

I think you are messing with l(alphabet) and 1.
If you wrote `(n-l)*(j+1)` then it would be = 5*5=25 results in final sum=10+25=35

Comment: You're extremely right!, I messed with the alphabet I think, that's why I was unable to spot the difference, Thank you :)